# Bugzilla 4.4.6 cannot save configuration settings

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, bugzilla

I've succesfully installed Bugzila 4.4.6 on Ubuntu Server 14 LTS, but then I get following message:

> Welcome, Marko Frelih .
>
> You are seeing this page because some of the core parameters have not
>   been set up yet. The goal of this page is to inform you about the last
>   steps required to set up your installation correctly.
>
> As an administrator, you have access to all administrative pages,
>   accessible from the Administration link visible at the bottom of this
>   page. This link will always be visible, on all pages. From there, you
>   must visit at least the Parameters page, from where you can set all
>   important parameters for this installation; among others:
>
> ```
> urlbase, which is the URL pointing to this installation and which will be used in emails (which is also the reason you see this page: as
> ```
>
> long as this parameter is not set, you will see this page again and
>   again).
>       cookiepath is important for your browser to manage your cookies correctly.
>       maintainer, the person responsible for this installation if something is running wrongly.
>
> Also important are the following parameters:
>
> ```
> requirelogin, if turned on, will protect your installation from users having no account on this installation. In other words, users
> ```
>
> who are not explicitly authenticated with a valid account cannot see
>   any data. This is what you want if you want to keep your data private.
>       createemailregexp defines which users are allowed to create an account on this installation. If set to ".*" (the default), everybody
>   is free to create his own account. If set to "@mycompany.com$", only
>   users having an account @mycompany.com will be allowed to create an
>   account. If left blank, users will not be able to create accounts
>   themselves; only an administrator will be able to create one for them.
>   If you want a private installation, you must absolutely set this
>   parameter to something different from the default.
>       mail_delivery_method defines the method used to send emails, such as sendmail or SMTP. You have to set it correctly to send emails.
>
> After having set up all this, we recommend looking at Bugzilla's other
>   parameters as well at some time so that you understand what they do
>   and whether you want to modify their settings for your installation.

Now, I have to setup core parameters and when I enter vales and press save button, I get following error:

> Software error:
>
> Error in tempfile() using template data/params.XXXXX: Could not create
>   temp file data/params.SjYXS: Permission denied at Bugzilla/Config.pm
>   line 270.
>
> For help, please send mail to the webmaster (webmaster@localhost),
>   giving this error message and the time and date of the error.
>   Which permissions do I have to set, bugzilla has been installed into `/usr/local/bugzilla-4.4.6` and in `/var/www/html` there is a symlink to installation directory:

```
xxx@conquistador:/var/www/html$ ls -asl
total 20
 4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Dec 28 08:50 .
 4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Dec 28 08:49 ..
 0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    25 Dec 28 08:50 bugzilla -> /usr/local/bugzilla-4.4.6
12 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11510 Dec 27 22:40 index.html
xxx@conquistador:/var/www/html$
```

Which permission do I have to set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your webserver doesn't have the ability to write to the $BUGZILLA_HOME/data/ directory. You need to allow that. In general, running checksetup.pl should set all the permissions correctly for you, as long as you've set $webservergroup correctly in the localconfig file.